# Multipart form submits and sends email but file upload fails with jQuery check

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a simple HTML form that can be filled out and the information emailed via the POST method. I recently added a file upload to the form - If i do no checks with Javascript/jQuery then it submits fine and the file uploads no problem. However if I use jQuery validation the form responds with the success message and I receive the email, all the information is there but the file upload fails.

Form:

```
<form class="smtcheck" style="font-family: Arial;" action="https://myurl.co.uk/emails/smt.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="formname" style="font-family: Arial;"><select style="font-family: Arial;" name="title">
    <option style="font-family: Arial;" selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Title</option>
    <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="Mr">Mr</option>
    <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="Miss">Miss</option>
    <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
    <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="Ms">Ms</option>
    <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="Sir">Sir</option>
    <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="Dr">Dr</option>
    <option style="font-family: Arial;" value="Mx">Mx</option>
    </select><input class="wipe" style="font-family: Arial;" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name*" required=""></div>
    <input class="wipe" style="font-family: Arial;" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address*" required="">
    <input class="wipe" style="font-family: Arial;" type="text" name="phone" value="Phone Number*" required="">
    <input class="wipe" style="font-family: Arial;" type="text" name="make" value="Make*" required="">
    <input class="wipe" style="font-family: Arial;" type="text" name="model" value="Model">
    <input class="wipe" style="font-family: Arial;" type="text" name="age" value="Age">
    <input class="wipe" style="font-family: Arial;" type="text" name="serial" value="Serial No">
    <input type="file" name="imgup" id="imgup">
    <input class="right" style="font-family: Arial;" type="submit" value="SEND"></form>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


    $(document).on("click","span.close",function(){$(this).parent().slideUp(300)})





    $('.smtcheck').submit(function(e){





        e.preventDefault();





        var error = false;


        var name = $("input[name='name']").val();

        var email = $("input[name='email']").val();

        var phone = $("input[name='phone']").val();

        var make = $("input[name='make']").val();



        if(name.length == 0){


        var error = true;


        var name = $("input[name='name']").addClass("error");
        alert("Please ensure you have filled out your name.");


        }else{

        var error = false;
        $("input[name='name']").removeClass("error");


        }





        if(make.length == 0){


        var error = true;


        var make = $("input[name='make']").addClass("error");
        alert("Please ensure you have filled out your trailer make.");


        }else{

        var error = false;
        $("input[name='make']").removeClass("error");


        }


        if(phone.length == 0){


        var error = true;


        var phone = $("input[name='phone']").addClass("error");
        alert("Please ensure you have filled out your phone number.");


        }else{

        var error = false;
        $("input[name='phone']").removeClass("error");


        }



        if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){


        var error = true;


        var email = $("input[name='email']").addClass("error");
        alert("Please ensure you have filled out your email.");


        }else{

        var error = false;
        $("input[name='email']").removeClass("error");


        }

        if(error == false){





        $.post("https://myurl.co.uk/emails/smt.php", $(".smtcheck").serialize(),function(result){





        if (result) {


                           $("input[type=submit]").remove();


                           $('.formresponse').show();


                            }else{


                            alert("Please ensure you have filled out all the required fields and try again.");


                        }

                        return false;
                    });


                }


    }); 


});
```

I've never tried doing an AJAX submit of a multipart form so unsure why the file fails to upload with the jQuery validation?

Comment: data from file input is not serialize when uaing `serialize()` method so  use ajaxForm library

Answer (score 0):

```js
var frm = $(document.formname);
var jdata = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will serialize all the input values except file inputs.if you want to do this, do form submit with ajax like,

```js
$(document).on("submit", "form#formname", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($("#formname").validationEngine('validate')) {
            $('.loader').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("action"),
                type: $(this).attr("method"),
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: new FormData(this),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (result) {
                },
                error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

You can show any success of error messages in ajax success/error if needed